# How to scrollIntoView in vue composition api that use script setup?

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have a parent app(parent.vue) that emit value from child app(MainMenu.vue) that used to scroll in spesific pageview by id in parent app, but when i run it give the error message `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`.

This is the parent app that i want to scroll in spesific pageview

`parent.vue`

```
<template>
  <section>
    <MainCover></MainCover>
    <QuotePage></QuotePage>
    <GroomBride id='1'></GroomBride>
    <TimeLines id='2'></TimeLines>
    <RunDown id='3'></RunDown>
    <SpecialInvitation></SpecialInvitation>
    <LiveStream></LiveStream>
    <OurMoment id='4'></OurMoment>
    <MessageBox id='5'></MessageBox>
    <FooterPage></FooterPage>
    <MainMenu @coba="onCoba" @page="navigation"></MainMenu>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup>
import QuotePage from '@/components/QuotePage.vue'
import MainCover from '@/components/MainCover.vue'
import GroomBride from '@/components/GroomBride.vue'
import TimeLines from '@/components/TimeLines.vue'
import RunDown from '@/components/RunDown.vue'
import SpecialInvitation from '@/components/SpecialInvitation.vue'
import OurMoment from '@/components/OurMoment.vue'
import MessageBox from '@/components/MessageBox.vue'
import FooterPage from '@/components/FooterPage.vue'
import MainMenu from '@/components/MainMenu.vue'
import LiveStream from '@/components/LiveStream.vue'


// Navigation handler
const navigation = val => {
  console.log(val);
  document.getElementById(val).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
}

</script>
```

This is the child app that i emit a value to parent,

`MainMenu.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="notification is-primary p-2">
              <!-- <span class="mr-4" @click="editEvent(day.id, event.details)"><fa :icon="['fas', 'pencil']" /></span>
              <span @click="deleteEvent(day.id, event.details)"><fa :icon="['fas', 'trash']" /></span> -->
          <span class="icon-text is-paddingless is-marginless">
              <span @click="navPage('1')" class="icon">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-heart" />
              </span>
              <!-- <span>Couple</span> -->
              <span @click="navPage('2')" class="icon">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-calendar-days" />
              </span>
              <!-- <span>Date</span> -->
              <span @click="navPage('3')" class="icon">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-map" />
              </span>
              <!-- <span>Location</span> -->
              <span @click="navPage('4')" class="icon">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-images" />
              </span>
              <!-- <span>Galleries</span> -->
              <span @click="navPage('5')" class="icon">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square" />
              </span>
              <!-- <span>Wishes</span> -->
          </span>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineEmits } from "vue";

const emit = defineEmits(['page']);


const navPage = (value) => {
    emit("page", value)
}

</script>
```

I consider that the error is in the accessing dom from script setup. I have tried but did'nt get solution, please help. Thanks

Comment: What does the `console.log(val);` show you?

Comment: number, from navpage in child app.

Comment: What does the code look like, where you use the two templates together?

Comment: sorry,,child app is similar to MainMenu. I use two template in parent.vue.

Comment: I have made a simplified working version of your code seen [here](https://shorturl.at/biqR9).  Since I can't reproduce, please see if maybe you can create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its done, i update my code

`MainMenu.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="notification is-primary p-2">
          <span class="icon-text is-paddingless is-marginless">
              <span @click="navPage('groom')" class="icon">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-heart" />
              </span>
              <!-- <span>Couple</span> -->
              <span @click="navPage('time')" class="icon">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-calendar-days" />
              </span>
              <!-- <span>Date</span> -->
              <span @click="navPage('run')" class="icon">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-map" />
              </span>
              <!-- <span>Location</span> -->
              <span @click="navPage('moment')" class="icon">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-images" />
              </span>
              <!-- <span>Galleries</span> -->
              <span @click="navPage('message')" class="icon">
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square" />
              </span>
              <!-- <span>Wishes</span> -->
          </span>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineEmits } from "vue";

const emit = defineEmits(['page']);


const navPage = (value) => {
    emit("page", value)
}

</script>
```

`parent.vue`

```
<template>
  <section>
    <MainCover></MainCover>
    <QuotePage></QuotePage>
    <div ref="groom">
      <GroomBride></GroomBride>
    </div>
    <div ref="time">
      <TimeLines></TimeLines>
    </div>
    <div ref='run'>
      <RunDown></RunDown>
    </div>
    <SpecialInvitation></SpecialInvitation>
    <LiveStream></LiveStream>
    <div ref='moment'>
      <OurMoment></OurMoment>
    </div>
    <div ref='message'>
      <MessageBox></MessageBox>
    </div>
    <FooterPage></FooterPage>
    <MainMenu @page="navigation"></MainMenu>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup>
import QuotePage from '@/components/QuotePage.vue'
import MainCover from '@/components/MainCover.vue'
import GroomBride from '@/components/GroomBride.vue'
import TimeLines from '@/components/TimeLines.vue'
import RunDown from '@/components/RunDown.vue'
import SpecialInvitation from '@/components/SpecialInvitation.vue'
import OurMoment from '@/components/OurMoment.vue'
import MessageBox from '@/components/MessageBox.vue'
import FooterPage from '@/components/FooterPage.vue'
import MainMenu from '@/components/MainMenu.vue'
import LiveStream from '@/components/LiveStream.vue'

import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const groom = ref()
const time = ref()
const run = ref()
const moment = ref()
const message = ref()


// // Navigation handler
const navigation = val => {
  console.log(val)
  if (val == 'groom') {
    groom.value.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
  } else if (val == 'time') {
    time.value.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
  } else if (val == 'run') {
    run.value.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
  } else if (val == 'moment') {
    moment.value.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
  } else if (val == 'message') {
    message.value.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
  }
}


onMounted( () => {
  navigation();
})

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).